# New input type Bundle Items

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

I am thinking to create a new input type for another type of select, because i have 2 types of them.

I want a new option that use a diferent template of: bunde_catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select.phtml

I want to select the new option at: Backend - product - bundle items - and when i add a new bundle item option, i want to choose between drop-down and new drop-down.

Because i wanna have the same type of select but just with little changes on frontend.

I can't manage with other solutions, and i have no idea if its a terrible idea to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing, i opt to use other design with the same codes unless the template that i want to use on this products, so on backend->product->design i associate the new template.